# Are MySQL user-defined functions part of the autocommit transaction of the statement that calls them?

Tags: mysql, transactions, user-defined-functions, autocommit

Suppose I have some InnoDB (or other transaction-aware) tables, and a user-defined function `MyFunction()` that reads or writes from those tables in the process of computing its return value.

Suppose further that autocommit is enabled (i.e. MySQL is operating in its default manner).

If I issue (for example) the statement:

```
UPDATE some_table SET col_a = MyFunction(col_b) WHERE col_c='apples';
```

Are *all* the table accesses (both the explicit updates of `some_table` and *also* whatever reads/writes `MyFunction()` is doing) part of a **single transaction**?

OR

Are the individual DML statements within `MyFunction()` each autocommitted as they execute... and then the cached changes to `some_table` applied as another separate transaction after that?

OR

...something else?

I've read through the MySQL documentation, but either I've missed something, or it isn't clear on this issue.  It does say that with autocommit ON, "as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent".  But (a) that only discusses modifications, and not (e.g.) row locking or isolation levels for `SELECT`s, and (b) more importantly, it doesn't clarify what counts a single "statement", when user-defined functions (that may contain data-modifying DML statements within them) are called from within some containing statement.

Could someone who's a MySQL expert please clarify?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each call of MyFunction() will be treated as a separate query and be committed itself.

SO even if you roll back the update on some_table, the changes made by MyFucntion will persist if autocommit is enabled.

That being said, you can simply disable autocommit for your session and then manually commit after the update.

Edit: Using a function this ways is VERY slow. For each row updated the function will be called once. It might be faster do the calculation of MyFunction on the update and do all update that MyFunction would do in separate updae statements.

Comment: So you're saying that if my UPDATE statement above matches 100 rows, then MyFunction() is called 100 times (each a single transaction), and the return values are cached.  Then the cached update values are applied to `some_table` in a single, final transaction?  It seems odd to me that this caching would be done, rather than calculating and updating each row at a time.

Comment: Not that I'm doubting you, but is there some kind of reference or something that you got your answer from?  Or test code, or something?  Or are you a MySQL developer?  Because I'd like to know where you got your information.